# Confused about loading ros_control and MoveIt! controllers

Tags: ros, ros-control, ros-kinetic, namespace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that MoveIt! expects the controllers.yaml to have `controller_list:` at the top, like this:

```
controller_list:
  - name: left_vel_based_pos_traj_controller
    joints:
      - left_ur5_shoulder_pan_joint
      - left_ur5_shoulder_lift_joint
      - left_ur5_elbow_joint
...
```

This puts all of the controller parameters in one giant string, with the parameter name `controller_list`. Then I have trouble loading the ros_control settings because they look for individual parameters. I get errors like:

> Could not load controller
> 'left_vel_based_pos_traj_controller'
> because the type was not specified.
> Did you load the controller
> configuration on the parameter server
> (namespace:
> '/left_vel_based_pos_traj_controller')?

Does anybody have an example of how you load a controller from controller_list? My best guess so far was:

```
  <node name="ros_control_controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false" output="screen" args="controller_list/left_vel_based_pos_traj_controller">
  </node>
```

I'm thinking I may need to load 2 nearly-identical yaml files: one for MoveIt!, one for ros_control.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/312534/confused-about-loading-ros_control-and-moveit!-controllers/) by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2331 on 2019-01-11

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like MoveIt! and ros_control need separate yaml files. I named the MoveIt! file `moveit_controllers.yaml`:

```
controller_list:
  - name: left_vel_based_pos_traj_controller
    action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    joints:
      - left_ur5_shoulder_pan_joint
      - left_ur5_shoulder_lift_joint
      - left_ur5_elbow_joint
      - left_ur5_wrist_1_joint
      - left_ur5_wrist_2_joint
      - left_ur5_wrist_3_joint
```

The yaml for ros_control. I named it `ros_control_controllers.yaml`:

```
# These controllers should match with what MoveIt! expects (moveit_controllers.yaml).
# Settings for ros_control control loop
hardware_control_loop:
   loop_hz: 125

# Settings for ros_control hardware interface
hardware_interface:
   joints:
     - left_ur5_shoulder_pan_joint
     - left_ur5_shoulder_lift_joint
     - left_ur5_elbow_joint
     - left_ur5_wrist_1_joint
     - left_ur5_wrist_2_joint
     - left_ur5_wrist_3_joint

# Publish all joint states ----------------------------------
joint_state_controller:
  type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
  publish_rate: 125

# Publish wrench ----------------------------------
force_torque_sensor_controller:
   type: force_torque_sensor_controller/ForceTorqueSensorController
   publish_rate: 125

# Left trajectories
left_vel_based_pos_traj_controller:
  action_ns: left_ur5_follow_joint_trajectory
  type: velocity_controllers/JointTrajectoryController
  joints:
    - left_ur5_shoulder_pan_joint
    - left_ur5_shoulder_lift_joint
    - left_ur5_elbow_joint
    - left_ur5_wrist_1_joint
    - left_ur5_wrist_2_joint
    - left_ur5_wrist_3_joint
  constraints:
    goal_time: 0.6
    stopped_velocity_tolerance: 0.05
    shoulder_pan_joint: {trajectory: 0.1, goal: 0.1}
    shoulder_lift_joint: {trajectory: 0.1, goal: 0.1}
    elbow_joint: {trajectory: 0.1, goal: 0.1}
    wrist_1_joint: {trajectory: 0.1, goal: 0.1}
    wrist_2_joint: {trajectory: 0.1, goal: 0.1}
    wrist_3_joint: {trajectory: 0.1, goal: 0.1}
  stop_trajectory_duration: 0.5
  state_publish_rate:  125
  action_monitor_rate: 10
  gains:
    #!!These values are useable, but maybe not optimal
    left_ur5_shoulder_pan_joint: {p: 1.2,  i: 0.0, d: 0.1, i_clamp: 1}
    left_ur5_shoulder_lift_joint: {p: 1.2,  i: 0.0, d: 0.1, i_clamp: 1}
    left_ur5_elbow_joint: {p: 1.2,  i: 0.0, d: 0.1, i_clamp: 1}
    left_ur5_wrist_1_joint: {p: 1.2,  i: 0.0, d: 0.1, i_clamp: 1}
    left_ur5_wrist_2_joint: {p: 1.2,  i: 0.0, d: 0.1, i_clamp: 1}
    left_ur5_wrist_3_joint: {p: 1.2,  i: 0.0, d: 0.1, i_clamp: 1}
```

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2019-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2020-02-28**:
Adding to my answer, for future sanity. The way ros_control works is:

A hardware_interface defines read/write functions for each actuator. When one of the default controllers gets loaded, it automatically hooks up with the hw_interface for whatever actuators ("resources") it controls. The user and the robot manufacturer usually shouldn't need to write their own controllers, they can use the default controllers. Somebody will need to write a hardware_interface for each type of robot, though.

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2020-04-03**:
If using multiple hardware interfaces of the type (like two position_controllers::JointTrajectoryControllers), namespacing is the way to go. Otherwise one controller will likely crash